# Replacing divs with background images with canvas elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to replace any divs that have background images with canvas elements with those background images drawn onto them.

I've got the basics working but I am slightly stumped by the difference in image quality between the `background-image` on a div and the same image drawn onto a canvas.

Here is the code I am using to do this:

```
$('#container div').each(function(){
    if($(this).css('background-image') != 'none'){
        var bgImage = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/^url|[\(\)]/g, '');
        var image = new Image();
        var attrs = $(this)[0].attributes;
        var dimensions = new Array();
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        dimensions.push($(this).height())
        dimensions.push($(this).width());

        $(canvas).attr('width',dimensions[0]);
        $(canvas).attr('height',dimensions[1]);
        $(canvas).css('background-image', 'none');

        for(var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++){
            $(canvas).attr(attrs[i].nodeName,attrs[i].nodeValue);
        }

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        image.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.height, image.width);
        }
        image.src = bgImage;

        $(this).replaceWith(canvas);
    }
});
```

Here are the results:

[image]

It looks like the image is being stretched for some reason but I've tried to `console.log` the width/height of the image that I am using in `drawImage` and the values match up to the image dimensions. The results show just a crop of the image - the real one is 900x4000ish pixels.

Here is a jsfiddle link showing the problem in action:

**http://jsfiddle.net/xRKJt/**

What is causing this odd behaviour?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `image.height` and `image.width` arguments from the call to `drawImage()`?

Comment: Then it gets only the height right and looks even more stretched - http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgJci.jpg

Comment: Which browsers are you testing with and trying to target? Can you setup a jsfiddle page?

Comment: I'm testing this in chrome but this will be for safari on ipad eventually. I'm in the process of setting up a jsfiddle page.

Comment: I tried your fiddle but there was no rendering.  However, what strikes me as funny is that the less stretched image - the canvas - has lower image quality.  This appears to be a rendering issue with the canvas object, whereas the background image is handled by the browser.

Comment: Whoops - I should have set the framework to `onDomReady` instead of `onLoad`. I have updated the link to a new one that should work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ha! (took some seconds to figure out)

Image has naturalWidth and naturalHeight attributes which reflect its pixel dimensions. Change your code

```
        image.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.naturalWidth, image.naturalHeight);
        }
```

Because the image is so large, if you open the image in the browser it zooms out it by default. I think you'll get those zoomed out width and height attributes if you try to access image.width and image.height. Or something along the lines.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, it still looks the same as it did before - http://jsfiddle.net/FMTqD/

Comment: Also you have width and height flipped in the code (not sure if that is purposeful)

Comment: If I put them the right way then it becomes really stretched. Flipping them seems to give me the right dimensions.

Comment: ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.height, image.width);
 <---- WRONG        dimensions.push($(this).height())
        dimensions.push($(this).width());
 <---- WRONG

Comment: Now that is embarrassing - I was thinking array.push put stuff at the start of the array rather than the end. So I had the wrong dimensions on my canvas to start with which messed up my image. Thanks for setting me straight!

Comment: No problem. Javascript array API is not exactly the pinnacle of human intelligence :)